# Why would an interpreted MATLAB function block be evaluated twice in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I have a Simulink model that includes the following subsystem.

[image: Simulink subsystem with interpreted MATLAB function]

The `bm_train_adapter` block will call a MATLAB function of the same name, passing all the input arguments in a single vector.

The subsystem has been given a sample time of 900 (secs), which is why all the signals are colored in red (for discrete signals).

However, in the debugger I have observed that the `bm_train_adapter` function gets called twice at each simulation timestep. This yields horribly wrong results since the function includes side-effects.

**Why is Simulink calling my interpreted MATLAB function more than once per timestep? How can I prevent this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that my model had algebraic loops caused by unit delay blocks in subsystems. To solve these loops, the solver had no choice but to evaluate some blocks more than once.

The solution was to move out all unit delays from their subsystems.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of your solver setup.  In your `Configuration Parameters` window, check out the `Solver Options` pane.

I believe the `discrete` and `ode1` solvers will call once per timestep.  `ode2` will call twice per timestep, `ode4` will call 4 times per timestep, etc.

This behavior is very helpful for simulating continuous dynamics, but it can be confusing when interacting with discrete elements.